# How do I deinstall Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

How do I delete all the files that I downloaded when I don't want them anymore. Yes I did that even though the install screen said not to. The files are on a USB-3 disk and the actual install was done on a different computer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the cache.
Just remove the directory, nothing more is needed

Comment: Thanks, that is not the problem. I didn't follow the instructions that said " You do not want to do this! This will install an enormous number of packages that you will never use, including debuginfo and source for every package." and got a bunch of files that I can;t delete. I now have 93 GB of file data and 1.4 Mega files installed. I blew it.